# Electron app just shows blank white screen on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, linux, node.js, arm

I am trying to load a program on an ARM machine which I was running on a Linux on an x86 machine. The program loads but just with a white screen. The program was developed using electron and when I run electron it shows the same white screen. Is it an architectural problem or with electron or node.js installation? Although I am getting the version for both node and npm and installation completed without any errors.

Comment: this question may be more appropriate in stackoverflow rather than this forum as it is not Raspberry Pi specific but more about the package Electron and Node.js. There are a number of questions about Electron and there is an Electron tag.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. 
Try installing electron with this command.

```
sudo npm install -g electron@1.6.11 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

And it should work without any errors